# Selenium WebDriver/Grid:Page is not loading after authentication in Firefox browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

I have created a test in C#  which launches Firefox browser,navigates to application URL which loads a authentication screen.Enter user credentials and hit submit.
Firefox is unable to navigate to application homepage after authentication is done.After clicking on sign-on the window remains blank and the test eventually times out. 
The application runs fine in Chrome and IE.Please note that I am running this test on selenium grid.
Firefox version:47.0.1
Selenium webdriver:2.53.1

Any help to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you execute tests in firefox only , without using grid, does that works?

Comment: Yes, If the test is run on my local development machine the test runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Timeout on the grid was increased and looks like this issue got resolved. I am now able to run the tests in Firefox